# Problemas com wiselinks e turbolinks

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Eu preciso que, após clicar num botão, apareça um modal, dentro desse modal há um form populado (ou não) com objetos rails. O problema é que não consigo mudar o header accept para js de forma que o rails renderize (não printe o código na tela mas sim execute) um .js.erb. Para resolver isso, resolvi colocar no botão um `data-remote=true` para que o .js.erb fosse executado mas a página não fosse recarregada, porém eu preciso mudar a url e por isso queria usar o wiselinks com o atributo `data-push=true`, mas os dois juntos não funciona. Alguém consegue me ajudar com o problema do modal ou consegue me ajudar a como eu faço o modal aparecer com o remote e alterar a url com o pushState???

PS. o ideal seria que ao clicar no botão o modal aparecesse (com o conteúdo debaixo da action anterior) e ao acessar a url diretamente o modal também fosse renderizado (com um conteúdo de outra action embaixo)

Comment: Você tento resolver isso usando o history api do html5, http://diveintohtml5.info/history.html ?

Answer (score 1):

Tu pode criar uma função que mostra o modal, baixar o JSON do objeto e fazer isto via JS:

```
function mostraModal(obj) {
  alert('Objeto: ' + obj.nome);
}
```

É claro que em vez de `alert()` tu pode usar algum plugin mais elaborado, usando HTML, etc.